# Domino Designer - Command to not save the file if the info is incomplete

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Good day! What command can I use so that the @command([filesave]) will not push through if there are there mandatory fields not yet filled-out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your validation to the input validation event of each mandatory field and/or you can add your validation to the querySave event of the form.

Comment: what are the example of validation formulas?

Comment: You use regular formula language. You can find this in the help. Or online: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_WRITING_AN_INPUT_VALIDATION_FORMULA.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add validation formulas on the mandatory fields and then use `@If(@Command([FileSave]);@Command([FileCloseWindow]);””)` to save and then close the window only if the save was successful (no errors).

Comment: Can hyou help me on this one? I have 2 combobox: C1 and C2. C1 have 2 choices: A and B. I want that if I choose A on the C1, D,E,F will be the only choices on C2 and if I choose B, G,H,I will be the choices. What formula can I choose? Thank you. Hopefully, I can get the most basic one.

Comment: Please put that as a separate question, since it is not related to your initial question.

Answer (score -1):

If the "FieldName" is empty then it is not saving and showing an message.

```
@If( 
FieldName = nil ; 
@Return(@Prompt([Ok] ; "Oppps" ; "Please fill the filed.")) ; 
"") ;

@Command([FileSave]); 
@Command([FileCloseWindow])
```